# notifyDataSetChange don't work properly on custom adapter

Tags: java, android, adapter

I'm trying to add some item to db, add on success to reload my listview in a Fragment.

Actually I do have something like that.

```
  db.collection("quizz").document().set(Quizz).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                            Toast.makeText(context, getString(R.string.quizz_done), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Quizz nQuizz = new Quizz(""+items.size()+1,""+mScore,uid,now);
                            items.add(nQuizz);
                            adapterquizz.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(context,getString(R.string.quizz_not_done), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: You should add items.add(Quizz) before notifyDataSetChanged() on Success func.

Comment: It's actually say that I cannot cast to Quizz, but thank it 's on the right way

Comment: Can you check your adapterquizz. Or share your adapter class.

Answer (score 0):

U only update the list when u init new instance of your adapter. U need to create an update function inside your adapter:

`public void updateData(List<Quizz> yourNewList) {
    data.clear(); // remove this if u just want to insert new item instead of clear all
    data.addAll(yourNewList)
    notifyDatasetChange()
}`

Call this from activity when u need to update data.

You don't need to pass the list to your adapter constructor anymore.

Comment: so i try : items.add(nQuizz);
             adapterquizz.updateData(items);  with items.add(nQuizz);
                                adapterquizz.updateData(items); nothing happen

Comment: Did u init List<Quizz> before? called : data = new ArrayList() inside your constructor

Comment: You have my adapter just before, i think i do

Comment: Can i see the code where u init your Adapter instance?

Comment: adapterquizz =  new QuizzAdapter(this.getContext() ,items, this);
        recyclerview.setAdapter(adapterquizz);

Comment: Can u debug into the items list, i don't think that your items is updated.

Comment: When I Log.d item.size it change

Comment: I probably find a way by recall the queries from database. Thanks a lot